# Multiple database with the same structure asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Im working in an application on MVC 5 and SQL Server to make queries from some databases(In the same server) with the same structure (same tables ; same fields; same relationships...) but different content.

The user should have the option to "switch" from one DB to another depending on what data he wants to view.

I´m looking for a way to change the DB (name) "on the way" in the DBContext or something like that, to query some DB o another.

Comment: You should update your question to describe what you really want.  As it stands the answer to the only question in this post is **yes**.

Comment: I'm curious why you have different databases if they have the same structure.

Comment: Well, I wonder that to, I'm doing a "satelital" app that gets data from existing databases of a system that has a whole new db for every project the user do. That's all I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just change the connection-string that you pass in to the DBContext constructor.

```
public DBContext Connect() {
    String[] dbNames = new String[] { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
    String connectionString = "Server=myServerAddress;Database={0};User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;";
    connectionString = String.Format( connectionString, dbNames[1] );

    return new DBContext( connectionString );
}
```

Comment: I have the <connectionStrings> section in the Web.config. What's the difference between removing them from the Web.config file and putting them on the DBContext constructor?

Comment: @Cesar_K-rrillo You can still keep them in your web.config file, but you still need to choose one to pass into the constructor. How are you currently passing the connection-string to your DBContext?

Comment: Well, since the db names are variables I was working with a unique db (connection string) to develop the app, so my question is, what´s the reason because the connection strings are in the web.config file? And if removing them from there is a "bad practice".

Comment: @Cesar_K-rrillo I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "db names are variables" or what "what's the reason" is referring to.

Comment: My app reads info from databases that are dynamically generated by another app, so they are variables in the time. This is the first time I work with a case like this, so I ever used a single or constants db connection strings in the Webconfig file and I don´t know what are the pros and cons of having (or not) the connection strings in the webconfig file. (Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: @Cesar_K-rrillo If you have the entire connection string in your web.config file then you can't do anything because that contains the database name. Look at my example and see how I'm using a format-string instead with a placeholder for the actual database name. You should do the same, but you can still store the connection-string (with the placeholder) in your web.config file, just make sure your DBContext doesn't read it from the web.config file directly.